# Which women have "romance" options in The Witcher 2?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm remembering that in the first game there were quite a few women that Geralt could pursue. So far I've only found Triss as a romantic prospect in the second game. Are there any others?

Comment: "Quite a few women"  That's the understatement of the year, I'm only in chapter 2 of the first game and I think there has already been at least 5.

Comment: And there will be many more to come. You're right; "quite a few" is definitely an understatement.

Comment: Calling Geralts relations with the fairer sex 'romance' is pushing it.

Comment: I can think of a a dozen other ways to phrase it but none of them are appropriate for Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Prostitutes**

in chapter 1, in basement of the tavern 2nd room. There are 4 of them.

in chapter 2, Brothel(tents) outside Kaedweni camp near Blue stripes encampment.
Talk to madame and she will offer you to choose between her 5 prostitutes.

- If you chose Roche's path you can access them anytime.
- If you chose Ioverth's path you can access them only during the quest "Where Is Triss Merigold?" when you get sent near kaedweni camp.

*Note:* almost all prostitutes have unique "introduction" scene.However the sex scenes are shared between them,game randomly picks animation out of few possible one and plays it with the corresponding prostitute model.

**Triss** in chapter 1, on the quest The Rose of Remembrance.

**Ves** in chapter 2 (roche's path),on the quest "Ave Henselt!" after you defeat all opponents in the arena.

**Mottle** in chapter 2 (Ioverth's path), if you saved her from burning building in chapter 1  she will be in front the western entrance to the Vergen.

**Succubus** in chapter 2 (Ioverth's path), on the quest "With Flickering Heart".

**Cynthia** in chapter 3 (Ioverth's path), on the quest "The Secrets of Loc Muinne". Available only if you have "Enhanced Edition" of the game.

---

***There are also some independent nude cutscenes:***

***Triss***

- In the Prologue she is in bed with geralt.
- In the beginning of chapter 3 (Ioverth's path) if you help Philippa lift the curse Triss will be transformed from figurine naked.

***Baroness LaVallette*** If you killed Arayan LaVallette in prologue then during the prison escape if you go through the floor hatch in one of the first cells after you get loose you will find her topless and about to be tortured.

***Phillipa*** in chapter 2 (Ioverth's path), in Vergen there are 2 scenes with her and her "apprentice",inside her house.

***Saskia*** in chapter 2 (Ioverth's path), on the quest in the harpy den if you collect all crystals and watch them on projector Saskia will appear naked in a dream of some dwarf.

---

[Detailed guide with conversation options](http://www.g4tv.com/thefeed/blog/post/723467/the-witcher-2-romance-guide-rated-teen-beat-the-latest-in-video-game-gossip/)

[Videos of love scenes](http://www.ign.com/wikis/witcher-2/Love_Scenes)

Comment: The Tortured Woman would be the Baroness LaVallette, and only if you killed Arayan earlier in the prologue. There's definitely no romance option for her.

Answer (score 10):

As you mentioned there is Triss in the first chapter. If you follow Roche's path there is also Ves in chapter 2. You have to fight in the Arena and win all the fights to pursue her.

Iorveth's path features a sidequest called "Of Flickering Heart", where, if you side with the Succubus, first Dandelion, and then Geralt get down with the mystic critter (and gets you drunk to boot).

Also on Iorveth's path, if you save the elven women from burning alive at the end of Chapter 1, you can find one elf woman just outside of Vergen that offers herself as thanks for rescuing her.

And there are of course the ladies of negotiable affection in the first two chapters.

Comment: Wanna make this answer community wiki for that purpose? I have some answers from Iorveth's path.

Comment: Hahaha, 'Ladies of negotiable affection'. I'll have to start using that in my day-to-day conversations.

Answer (score 0):

**Spoiler alert:** I don't know about romance, but when it comes to full digital nudity then if you follow Ioerveth's path there's a Succubus, the elf you saved in chapter 1 and there are always the hookers...

So about a third of the options you had in the original.

Answer (score 0):

I know you do Triss.... If you follow Iorveth's path, there's the Succubus, Mottle, Cynthia, also, when you reach Roche's encampment, there's a "working woman's" tent where you have the choice of five ladies.